# How to apply transpose method in MYSQL, Getting rows as collumns

Tags: mysql, pivot

have a table of ideas that stores responses from evaluators and stores as one row per evalautor For ex : Evalautor 1 evaluated idea A then in table record gets added as

```
IDEA A, COMMENTS , EVALUATOR ID
```

as single idea have 4 evaluator response and i need to show data in this format

```
IDEA ID ||. EVALUATOR 1 || EVALUATOR 2|| EVALUATOR 3 || EVALUATOR 4
1 --        Comments --    Comments --   Comments --    Comments
```

Need assistance in creating logic to get information in format given above.

Query i am running :

```
 SELECT * from Toy_ideas GROUP BY evaluator id
```

but getting results as

```
Ideaid -- comments -- evaluator id
```

Comment: Please provide script with exact table structure you want to start with and some example data (https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is that list of evaluators fixed or can it be changed?

Answer (score 0):

As yu will have different evaluators ver the time a dynamic approach is called for

if you have only a static, you can select the variable @sql and get ten result of the dynamc query

> ```
> CREATE table Toy_ideas  (IDEA int, COMMENTS varchar(50), EVALUATOR_ID int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Toy_ideas VALUES(1,'coment1',1),
> (1,'coment2',2),
> (1,'coment3',3),(1,'coment4',5),
> (2,'coment5',2),
> (2,'coment6',4),(2,'coment7',5),
> (3,'coment8',2),(3,'coment9',5)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>     CONCAT(
>       'MAX(IF(EVALUATOR_ID = ',
>      EVALUATOR_ID,
>       ', `COMMENTS`,NULL)) AS `',
>       CONCAT('EVALUATOR ',EVALUATOR_ID), '`'      
>     )
>     ORDER BY EVALUATOR_ID
>   ) 
>   INTO @sql
> FROM Toy_ideas; 
> SET @sql = CONCAT('select IDEA,',@sql,' from Toy_ideas
> group by `IDEA`');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> IDEA | EVALUATOR 1 | EVALUATOR 2 | EVALUATOR 3 | EVALUATOR 4 | EVALUATOR 5
> ---: | :---------- | :---------- | :---------- | :---------- | :----------
>    1 | coment1     | coment2     | coment3     | null        | coment4    
>    2 | null        | coment5     | null        | coment6     | coment7    
>    3 | null        | coment8     | null        | null        | coment9
> ```

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2118357b2819abcf68cb5750318a10c4)*